# how to prevent method from being instantiated

Tags: c#, oop

How I can Prevent interface method that I implemented in a class from being instantiated.

```
public interface Interface1
{
    void Show();
}

public class ABC : Interface1
    {

        public void Show()
        {
            // any thing
      console.WriteLine(:Hello");
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ABC a = new ABC();

        }
    }
```

Here in program class I dont want to create the access this method.

Comment: Just have it as an empty method? (remove the throw) then it doesn't matter if its called - otherwise if that is all that is in the interface, just don't have ABC implement the interface

Comment: Sorry, but "I dont want to create the access this method" doesn't make any sense to me? What is your problem?

Comment: @Sayse I dont want to call this method from ABC instance that I created into Program class

Comment: You really can't instantiate a method. You can instantiate a class, then call the method on that instance. Or if it is a static method, you can call the method without instantiating the class (a singleton instance of the class is instantiated for you automatically without you having to think about it, and the static methods are called on that singleton instance).

Comment: @IMMORTAL so what is the purprose for implementing that interface by `ABC` class?

Comment: @IMMORTAL - Just stop your fingers from typing it, if its an empty method then you can call it all day long and it will do nothing

Comment: If you just don't have the correct implementation ready yet, or if your concrete class is never going to provide an implementation for that particular method for whatever reason, the proper thing to do (probably) is actually to throw a NotImplementedException() from the method body.

Comment: @Mithrandir my problem when i create the instance of ABC class in Program Class like a.Show() is display but I dont want it to access to other class

Comment: @Sayse if know ans olz reply me ow please stop ur non sence comment whatever I print in show method

Comment: @IMMORTAL - My comment(s) *could* be a viable answer but I don't think it is developed enough to post as one; even your last comment suggests (to me) you don't think it is either. It may help if you further explained your problem.

Comment: @Sayse Sorry for last comment but at interview that person ask me such scenario but he told me that I dont want that method to be access in any other class

Comment: @IMMORTAL - It sounds like the interviewer wanted you to change it from a `public` method to a `private` one

Comment: @Sayse Yes dude now you got it what exactly I mean... thankx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [explicit interface implementation](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-gb%2Flibrary%2Fms173157.aspx&ei=ys7-U4KzHYzraKzAgZAI&usg=AFQjCNHdz91nBiV5h8nD7nA8xlElByXo0w&sig2=EJgO8AwXQQaz3ZODe2FV5w&bvm=bv.74035653,d.d2s), if you really only want the method to be available via an expression of the interface type:

```
void Interface1.Show()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You can't remove the possibility of calling it completely though - that would clearly break the fact that `ABC` implements the interface at all. Indeed, if it's not going to *really* implement the whole interface, you should consider whether or not it *should* declare that it implements the interface.

With explicit interface implementation as above: we'd have:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.Show(); // Error
Interface1 iface = abc;
iface.Show(); // Fine at compile time; will throw your NotImplementedException
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can't

A class that implements an interface needs to implement them all as instance methods. That is how Interface are meant to be used by design, as a contract for the Class.

If you are going to have a static method, you will not need an Interface to hold the contract as there will only be one global static implementation.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent other classes from seeing and calling the method, then mark it private.

But then you can't use it to implement the interface, because interface methods are by definition public.

Also, if you mark the method private and the calling code has sufficient permissions (same assembly), then the caller could still call your method using Reflection.

You could walk the call stack within your method to see where it is being called from and determine if you like the caller, and either shortcut out of the method or throw an exception if you don't.

But what is the real requirement, here? Is the underlying issue data security? Does the method do something dangerous (data corruption possibility, or the possibility of extracting the cooling rods in a nuclear reactor at the wrong time or something?)

Understanding the requirements will help you determine the correct solution.